# Localização de pseudo-elementos (xpath)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automatização, xpath, testes-automatizados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou com o seguinte cenário (print anexado).
A fim de automatização do meu teste, gostaria de localizar a mensagem "Product successfully added to your cart" em meu teste através de xpath.
Como procedo com o ::before??

Aguardo algum retorno!

Obrigado!

Comment: Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe alguns espaços entre o texto, você precisará usar a função `normalize-space` para encontrar apenas o texto *"Product successfully added to your cart"*.

```
//h2[normalize-space(text()='Product successfully added to your cart')]
```